# Getting Html.LabelForModel() to work for main model of the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, t4

I am trying to customize the T4 templates for Create/Edit/Details/Delete/Index views in Asp.net MVC4 (Razor).

What I **effectively** want to do is add a [Display(Name="MyFancyModelName")] attribute to my model and then in the View want to add @Html.LabelForModel() to get a label for it.

Is there a builtin/easyway of achieving something like this?

```
// .cs
[Display(Name="FancyViewModel")]
public class MyViewModel
{
    ....
}

// .cshtml
@model MyViewModel

@Html.LabelForModel()
```

Comment: apply your [Display] annotation to the data member of the class, not the class itself

Comment: Well i understand that. My questions is how do i do it for the Model itself.

Comment: OIC. D'Oh. twice. me stupid and y that no work?

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: Impossible to find any good documentation on how to annotate a model. Very Strange.